# Drag UIView containg UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have been having trouble trying to drag a UIView that has a UIScrollView within it. The UIView drags up from the bottom of the screen, when it has hit the top you can use the UIScrollView inside it. When the user scrolls to the top of the UIScrollView, the UIView should drag down with their finger.

It should work like the Google Maps popup when you click a pin.

**Update**: I can get the dragging up of the UIView working (touchesMoved) that changes the Y value. The main functionality I am having problems with is the dragging down of the UIView when the user touches inside the UIScrollView. I want the user to still be able to drag the scrollview as normal until it reaches the top at which point the dragging action should then move the parent UIView down off the screen.

Update 2: This is the code you suggested to turn off the user interaction:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y<=0){
        scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }else{
        scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't have one answer. It is a full feature. Make your question more specific please.

Just for the sake of answering, you will need to make the view draggable by finger which means adding Gesture recognisers or overriding touchesBegun, touchesEnded, touchesCanceled and touchesMoved, on the view itself. Then you will need logic that connects the scroll view to the view and tells it when to take the touches' ownership. 

Can you please make your question a bit more specific so that we can help you?


Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most apps handle this scenario by using the UIScrollViewDelegate method scrollViewDidScroll.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // check the scrollView.contentOffset.y to see if you 
    // have reached the top of the scroll view.
}
```

You can then check the contentOffset and continue with your dragging code the way you want.

Comment: Okay, how would I then transfer the dragging action from the scrollview to changing the Y of the UIView

Comment: @GeorgeGrover You would disable userInteraction on the scroll view which would then cause the touchesMoved to be fired on the containing view. At this point your code should work as intended.

Comment: That works thanks, but the problem is now that you cant scroll/drag  the scrollview back up after you have disabled its interaction...
See update 2 for code I used

Comment: @GeorgeGrover You would want to enable user interaction in your dragging code once the view is off the screen. Also you are checking <= 0, which it will always be zero at rest.

Comment: @GeorgeGrover Also, if you like my answer, please don't forget to up-vote and accept.

Comment: So how would I get around the <= 0 issue as like you said it will be at 0 on rest? Also it requires the user to do this in two steps..drag scroll view to top and then the second drag moves the uiview. Is it possible to do this in the same drag gesture...move to top of scrollview and then move uiview down? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57339/discussion-between-bstahlhood-and-george-grover).